# Ajax response in console it's ok, but in php page doesn't arrive

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I was searching for some time an answer for my problem, but every solution I tried doesn't work.

I have a html select

```
    <select id="exampleid">
     <option>Option1</option>
     <option selected>Option2</option>
     <option>Option3</option>
    </select>
```

Ajax request

```
    $('#exampleid').change(function(){

       var aabbcc = $(this).val().trim();
       $.post("_ws/rca.php?action=brands", {aabbcc:aabbcc}, function(response) {
       console.log('search is: ' + aabbcc + ', Response from PHP script: ' + response);
         });
})
```

This return in console:

```
search is: Option2, Response from PHP script: array(1) {
  ["aabbcc"]=>
  string(27) "Option2"
}
```

PHP

```
if($action == 'brands'){ //action is relevant for link where send the ajax
var_dump($_POST['aabbcc']);
exit;
}
```

The problem is, the $_POST returns empty array.
I cheched with print_r and var_dump also.
Apparently AJAX sends correct request, but in PHP doesn't arrive.

I checked for 404 errors or something similar, but everything seems to be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say $_POST is empty, but from your console output it looks like the data was received fine since we can see output from the var_dump.

Comment: @zkip php return a array and it's not empty.. `["aabbcc"]=>
  string(27) "Option2"`

Comment: @Zkip please post your PHP code

Comment: Php Code is if($action == 'brands'){ var_dump($_POST['aabbcc'])} exit;}. And return in php page is array(0) { }, and aabbcc variable doesn't exist. Yes $_POST is empty, but output in console it's ok.

Comment: @Ruchish Parikh aabbcc is a variable, I don't want to be string

Comment: @FastSnail yes, this is the reason for this question. In console everything seems fine, but when I access specific php page will return only a empty array.

Comment: Your page is returning the right response, you don't know how ajax works and how post variables work

the ajax is opening a different page from the page you have opened and the post variables are not global variables so the values are only on the page that the ajax called

Comment: @Zkip what do you mean by `but when I access specific php page will return only a empty array.` .it's a post request you should post data.if you visit this page `rca.php` page then you not posting any data.only get will work

Comment: @FastSnail I want to use this variable as parameter for a url. So, in my thinking I grab selected option and send to php with ajax, after that in php with $_POST I grab this variable and concatenate with url. Am I correct ? or missing something ?

Comment: Any new ideas ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main page:

```
<select id="exampleid">
         <option>Option1</option>
         <option>Option2</option>
         <option>Option3</option>
    </select>

<div class="result">none</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#exampleid').change(function(){  
            var aabbcc = $(this).val().trim();
            $.post("rca.php?action=brands", {aabbcc:aabbcc}, function(response) {
                console.log('Search is: ' + aabbcc + ', Response from PHP script: ' + response);
                $( ".result" ).html( response );
            });
        })
</script>
```

And this is your callback **rca.php**

```
if($_GET['action']=='brands') {
        echo 'PHP: '.$_POST['aabbcc'];
        return;
    }
```